# Bleak/Python: BLE filtered scan with timeout, and getting AD data

Tags: python, bluetooth

My task is to scan for x seconds for a BLE device with a specific name or service UUID, then get the RSSI value for returned device(s).

Bleak seems to be the best option as far as I can see. I've been going through examples and can scan (no filter or timeout) with BleakScanner, or perform a filtered scan with BleakScanner.find_device_by_filter (but can't see how to get the RSSI)

The filtered scan looks best, but how can I get the RSSI for the returned device?
Here is my code example so far:

```
import asyncio
from bleak import BleakScanner
from bleak import BleakClient
from bleak import BleakError
import time

async def main():
    try:
        device = await BleakScanner.find_device_by_filter(lambda d, ad: d.name == "Foo", timeout=4.0)
        if not device:
            raise BleakError(f"Nothing found.")
        else:
            print("Device found")
            print(device)
    except BleakError as e:
        print(e)

asyncio.run(main())
```

This is running on a RPi Zero W with Raspbian lite